# Android Studio Error "Unexpected end of file"

Tags: java, android, android-studio

When i make this xml file it gives me an error, "unexpected end of file".

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
 android:gravity="center_vertical"
 android:id="@+id/list_item_forecast_textview" />
```

I have a java class referencing the the id of this textview, but it "cannot resolve symbol 'list_item_forecast_textview'.

How do i get rid of the unexpected end of file error and fix the id reference issue?

Comment: The parent of any xml resource file cannot be a `TextView`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your xml looks fine to me and as I tried same snippet as you provided with added text for display, I find no issue.

"id reference issue" -- since your resources are not compiled properly, R.java doesn't have reference to your TextView and hence in java class(say, Activity) won't be able to find your TextView.

Probably, you might try "Clean Project" and/or "Rebuild Project". If not helpful, try restarting your Android Studio itself.[image]